# KnockoutJS map value to function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tdRCB/3/

I have an `observableArray` in my `viewModel` named `filterInfo`.
I have many html-controls to create filters (inputs, selects, etc)

What is the best way to get `filterInfo` containing all values in my html controls?
For example:

I have in input value `123` and in select value `1`, so I need, that my filterArray contains two elements:

```
[{field: 'title', value: '123'}, {field: 'type', value: 1}]
```

If my input is empty and I selected in dropdown list only second element, resulting array will be:

```
[{field: 'type', value: 2}]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have written sample for your example. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ivanov_vitaly/tdRCB/6/

Comment: Yes, it works. But this way, I have to create so many observables... each observable per filter. Is it possible to get desired without it?

Comment: If you will have certain amount of filters I think this approach will be good choice. In other case if you plan to add more filters and more types I suggest you to create filter entity with all required attributes and template to display filters. In this template you will make decision how to display filter base on type and so on. I described this approach in my article, but it is written in Russian. I believe you will understand my solution by fiddle samples in the article http://delmadman.blogspot.com/2012/01/javascript-c-knockoutjs.html